# When requesting the OpenAI API in Flutter on a Windows environment, an error message "The semaphore timeout period has expired" is returned

Tags: flutter, openai-api, flutter-http, flutter-windows

I receive an error message from Flutter saying :

> "The semaphore timeout period has expired".

However, it returns results normally in Chrome and Android.
I have been searching for solutions for a long time but haven't been able to solve it.

Below are my system environment and code.
Could you please help me resolve this issue?
Thank you.

Flutter Doctor Result :

[image: flutter doctor result]

My Code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  getResponse() async {
    final res = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://api.openai.com/v1/models'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization':
            'Bearer $openaiKey',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
    );
    final resJson = jsonDecode(res.body);
    // ignore: avoid_print
    print(resJson);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              'Test',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: getResponse,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried other APIs and they return normally, but only when requesting the OpenAI API do I encounter this error.

Error Info :

> [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled
> Exception: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
> #0      IOClient.send io_client.dart:94 
> #1      BaseClient._sendUnstreamed base_client.dart:93 
> #2      _withClient http.dart:166 
> #3      _MyHomePageState.getResponse main.dart:35  Lost connection to device. Exited (sigterm)

Comment: This is a network issue, awkward